# Reading Input From Textbox

Tags: c++, winapi

I have problem to read data from second textbox which is `IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT`. I only able to display content for first textbox which is `IDC_MAIN_INPUT`. I have tried various ways to solve but still cannot solve the problem. So far here is my code :

```
switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
                char *bufIn, *bufOut;
                int lenIn = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_INPUT));
                int lenOut = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT));
                bufIn = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, lenIn + 1);
                GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_INPUT, bufIn, lenIn + 1);
                bufOut = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, lenOut + 1);
                GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT, bufOut, lenOut + 1);
                MessageBox(NULL, bufIn, "String", NULL);
                MessageBox(NULL, bufOut, "String", NULL);
                //MessageBox(NULL, input, "Title Here", MB_OK);
                mc.application(bufIn, bufOut);
            }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateObjects(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if the return value from `GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT)` is not NULL. if it's NULL then the IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT control does not exist.

Comment: I have already declared IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT in .h file but still cannot get data from IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT.

Comment: what is the relevance of } before the break?

Comment: it is a switch inside switch..please read new updated codes

Comment: @user3479771: it's not a question if IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT is declared or not (if it wasn't declared, the program wouldn't compile). The question is: does the control IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT exist in your window ? Does as I suggested in my previous comment and check if `GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_OUTPUT)` returns NULL.

Comment: Post the resource script for your dialog. Or the code constructing the in-memory dialog template, if that is how you are constructing the dialog.